# Center buttons inside column

Tags: css, bulma

I'm using Bulma. Consider the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title">
        Welcome! :)
      </h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="/login" class="button">Login now!</a>
        <a href="/register" class="button">Register now!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, the title is centered but the buttons aren't. Of course, if we set `display: block;` to the div which groups together the buttons, they get centered as well. But I couldn't find any example and I'm not sure if that's the way to go here.

Is there a more "Bulma-like" way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about that.
I tried to reproduce the issue but it seems that the buttons are centered.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.0/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title">
        Welcome! :)
      </h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="/login" class="button">Login now!</a>
        <a href="/register" class="button">Register now!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe there are other rules that overrides this behavior?

EDIT:

It seems that in the same version between 0.4.0 and 0.8.0 they take advantage of the `flex box` layout.

In the example that you shared the `buttons` class has the `display: flex-box` but it miss the property `justify-content: center;` for centering the content of that div.
I don't know if it is the expected behavior or a bug.

Here a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gix_lg/73vmofqa/1/

Comment: First of all, you seem to be using an old Bulma version. The CDN seems to use 0.4.0 but I'm using 0.8.2. Here's an example of my problem I had: https://tribeio.herokuapp.com/ Now the problem seems to be, that the .buttons class overwrites the display tag (but I'm not fully sure yet), which leads to the behavior since it now isn't captured by `has-text-centered`. See https://jsfiddle.net/8qdmxp3L/

Comment: Thanks. I did more research and it turns out, I somehow didn't read the documentation not carefully enough. (I even did it several times) but the proper way to do set the aligment of a .buttons div is .is-centered, .is-right, .is-left. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried " is-vcentered" instead of "has-text-centered" ? 
Also, you can use empty columns by using a div with a class="column" to create horizontal space around .column elements, or use .is-centered on the parent .columns element

Have you tried to inspect your page to see the css?

Comment: It seems that the `.buttons` class applies a display which disturbs the behavior. Althought I'm not fully sure yet.

Comment: You're right. I think gixlg has your answer. Cheers mate!